# Pass pandas sub dataframe to master dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which I am doing some work on

```
d={'x':[2,8,4,-5,4,5,-3,5],'y':[-.12,.35,.3,.15,.4,-.5,.6,.57]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df['x_even']=df['x']%2==0
```

subdf, get all rows where x is negative and then square x and then multiple 100 to y

```
subdf=df[df.x<0]
subdf['x']=subdf.x**2
subdf['y']=subdf.y*100
```

subdf's work is completed. I am not sure how I can incorporate these changes to the master dataframe (df).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your current code should give you a `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning.

To avoid this you could do the following:

```
df.loc[df.x<0, 'y'] = df.loc[df.x<0, 'y']*100
df.loc[df.x<0, 'x'] = df.loc[df.x<0, 'x']**2
```

Which will change your `df`, without raising a warning and there is no need to merge anything back.

Comment: close. The problem is when I execute the first line, the second value becomes false and does not evaluate. How can I evaluate both of them?

Comment: Just change the order of the lines, so that `x` is overwritten at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.merge(subdf,df,how='outer')
```

This does what I was asking for. Thanks for the tip Primer